# How to make regex case-insensitive?

Tags: javascript, regex, case-insensitive

I have this javascript code but when i send this: asd.JPG the regex fails to me..

```
if (data.match(/([^\/\\]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff|tif)$/i))
     return { filename: RegExp.$1, ext: RegExp.$2 };
else
     return { filename: "invalid file type", ext: null };
```

So I want that the regex looks at the extension as case-insensitive.
I tried this but it fails:

```
data.match(/([^\/\\]+)\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff|tif)$/i)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ecThT/  The `i` at the end of the regex makes it case-insensitive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'fail'? For what input are you getting an incorrect output? What output do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: <s>**Okay, this is really weird** StackOverflow is showing that *I* added the backslash before the `.` in the question, but **I did not**. I just highlighted the code and clicked the `{}` button. @user: I've just gone and removed it again. If that backslash *is* in your code, you can go back and edit it back in.</s> The backslash was there, it's just that since it wasn't formatted as code, it wasn't showing. *whew* @user: This demonstrates the value of formatting the code, to avoid misunderstandings (@KooilInc's answer is based on that misunderstanding).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Check the source of the original question, it is there.

Comment: fail means that i get "invalid file type" just check it with the input asdas.JPG

Comment: @Felix: No, the backslash was there in the original, it just wasn't showing because there wasn't any formatting. When @digger (and then I, since it got reverted) formatted it correctly, the backslash that was already there showed up. (You can tell by using the "view source" option.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes I noticed that too and changed my comment already ;)

Comment: @Felix: LOL The joy of editing comments...

Comment: @user719001: You must do something else wrong. See the code in my comment. It works. So it is **not** a problem of the expression if you have it exactly like that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `i` flag you have on the end (`/.../i`) should be doing it.

(CW because let's face it, one shouldn't earn rep for this sort of thing... :-) )

Comment: because this site format my backslash - I took this functino from here: http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-parse.php at the end there is the function

Comment: @user: It's up to you to format things properly. We're all coders, it shouldn't be difficult. See the links in my comment on the question.

Comment: This is weird, now it works. And I didnt do anything =D Dont you love this "I didnt do nothing..." =]]

Comment: Why should someone not gain rep for this sort of thing? I think they should its the whole point of the site to ask questions that are helpful to others. You give someone rep if the question they asked led you to the answer.