# Explain following RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I was looking at "duplicate words" algorithm and I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497316/how-to-detect-duplicate-words-from-a-string-in-java) which was using following regex.

`(?i)\\b(\\w+)\\b[\\w\\W]*\\b\\1\\b`

I tried to interpret the RegEx by using following site http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp but I am having hard time .. Can someone breakdown the regex for me and explain it to me ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually come up with your solution you can understand and maintain?

Comment: Also searching for "explain regexp" would point you to sites like [this one](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3Fi%29%5Cb%28%5Cw%2B%29%5Cb%5B%5Cw%5CW%5D*%5Cb%5C1%5Cb), which, honestly, will most likely tell you the same as any answers to this question. (Just make sure to undouble the backslashes, that's a Javaism, not actual RE syntax.)

Answer (score 9):

```
 (?i)      - case insensitive flag
 \\b       - word boundary
 (\\w+)    - 1 or more word characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9) in a captured group
 \\b       - word boundary
 [\\w\\W]* - 0 or more word or non-word characters
 \\b       - word boundary
 \\1       - the group previously captured
 \\b       - word boundary
```

You may want to look at the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html) for Regular Expressions. All these are explained there.

**Multiple uses of Boundary**
If you look at the Java tutorial for [Boundary Matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) you will see what it is matching, i.e. a boundary of a word. Since this is looking for duplicate words it is making sure that the match is indeed the entire word and not words containing the word.

**Case Insensitive**
As mentioned by Phsemo this is used so that the `\\1` matching group with still match if the case is different. i.e consider if the first word in a sentence was repeated.

**Use of `[\\w\\W]*`**
Again as mentioned by Phsemo this is probably used in place of `.` (which is a regex special character for any character, except this is not guaranteed to match newline characters [See this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html). `.*` could be used in place of this if the dotall flag `(?s)` was also included) so that newline characters are matched. And the quantifier of `*` (0 or more) so that if the next word is a duplicate then it is matched and also if there are words/characters in between the duplicates they are matched.

Comment: Nice and simple +1. Also `[\\w\\W]` was probably used instead of `.` to also match new line character. Also if someone would wonder why `(?i)` is used here is to let `\\1` match group one characters case insensitive.

Comment: Sometimes in languages I see stuff like `/regex/i` for case insensitive.  Would those same languages let you use `/(?i)regEx/` as a synonym?  What's the difference between these?

Comment: is it possible if you can explain why `\b` has been used multiple times ? why `[w\W]` is used etc ?

Comment: @tieTYT What languauge's? I can't say I've seen that before, but I'm guessing that it would be language dependant.

Comment: @JavaDevil http://stackoverflow.com/a/5744627/61624

Comment: @pshemo Instead of the cryptic `[\\w\\W]*` I prefer `(?is)` at the front then simply `.*`, `(?s)` being the "dotall" switch so dot matches newline.

Comment: @tieTYT No those languages most likely wouldn't let you replace it like you say as it would likely not be recognised but that languauges regex parser - try it in a jsfiddle

Comment: @JavaDevil Doesn't work in javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/xRXQq/  I don't know much about regex, but I'm getting the impression it's fragmented like browser compatibility is.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes I also prefer combining `(?is)` and using `.` instead of `[\\w\\W]`. I assume that this regex was created by someone who either didn't know about `dotall` flag, or couldn't use it (like in JS, if w3shools is not laying [dot `.`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_dot.asp) also can't match new line there but JS regex don't have dotall [flag](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) so it seems that `[\\w\\W]` must be used there).